# Papier tue-mouches, papier à mouches*, papier-mouches* ; « flypaper » : fonction implicite/explicite dans le nom/adjectif composé ?

Tags: prépositions, verbes, comparaison-de-langues, mots-composés

Il y a le *papier tue-mouches* ([Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/tue-mouches/80168/locution), [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tue-mouche)), et le [*ruban anti-mouches*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attrape-mouche#Le_ruban_anti-mouches), et que de subtilité entre l'adhésion involontaire à l'un ou l'autre. J'ai vérifié que c'était en effet le *flypaper* en langue anglaise ([Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=FLYPAPER&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs), [GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=1299042)). Ce qui saute aux yeux en comparant brièvement c'est qu'en français on a la référence directe à l'action sur l'insecte (*tue(r)*, *contre les*) ; on n'a pas à première vue *papier/ruban à mouches* ou *papier/ruban pour mouches* même si ce n'est pas incompréhensible. Par ailleurs on a le [*tue-insectes électrique*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=18059396), différent...

---

- Qu'est-ce qui détermine qu'on forme le nom composé avec explicitement l'action
  (*tuer*) ou un élément comme [*anti-*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/anti-) ici et non avec des
  prépositions (*à, pour, contre,* etc.) ou sans verbe ni préposition apparente, avec deux noms (*flypaper*), pour rendre l'idée de la fonction ou de la
  destination ; on a bien *fer à friser* etc. ?

  - Est-ce qu'on a un
    [phénomène](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=s%C3%A8che-cheveux%2Cs%C3%A9choir%20%C3%A0%20cheveux&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cs%C3%A8che%20-%20cheveux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cs%C3%A9choir%20%C3%A0%20cheveux%3B%2Cc0) similaire avec *sèche-cheveux* par opposition à
    *séchoir à cheveux* ? De quel phénomène s'agit-il ?
  - L'emploi du verbe conjugué dans l'adjectif *tue-mouches*, est-ce bien la 3<sup>e</sup> personne du singulier ; peut-on rappeler pourquoi ? Est-ce généralement une indication que c'est plus
    contemporain/récent qu'un nom composé avec une préposition (comme *fer à repasser*) ?

Comment: Ça se retrouve aussi dans les noms simples: _insecticide_.

Comment: @mouviciel En effet, mais pourquoi alors n'a-t-on pas _papier insecticide_, par exemple. J'ai besoin de quelques jalons pour aller plus loin dans ma réflexion (vu 0 expertise). Merci !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Les mots composés en **tue-** sont rares, guère plus d'une dizaine, et il sont peu utilisés en dehors de **tue-mouche** (papier et amanite) et au sens figuré de **tue-tête** et **tue-l'amour**. au sens propre, ils désignent surtout les plantes et parfois les dispositifs susceptibles de tuer un animal ou quelqu'un/quelque chose.

Au contraire, les mots en **anti-** sont très nombreux, une ou deux centaines. Il désignent tout ce qui est susceptible de repousser/combattre quoi que ce soit, sans forcément le tuer. **Papier anti-mouche** est peu usité mais compréhensible.

L'utilisation des prépositions **à** ou **pour** fait perdre la notion d'hostilité, **papier à mouche** et **papier pour mouche** ne permettent pas de deviner quel est l'usage du papier.

La préposition ***contre*** inclus elle bien cette notion de résistance, mais elle est plus faible qu'avec **anti-** ou **tue-**, d'autant plus que **contre-** peut aussi simplement indiquer la proximité ou un assemblage (contre-plaqué, contre-amiral, ...). <s>Contre-mouche</s> n'existe pas et serait difficilement compréhensible.

Comment: Merci, et donc _tue-_ serait un simple cas particulier, ou un petit sous-ensemble. Vous avez une idée de l'époque à laquelle les mots avec _anti-_ apparaissent en majorité, le cas échéant ?

Answer (score 1):

"tue-mouches" est le concept général et englobe plusieurs types de tue-mouches, pas uniquement le ruban anti-mouches.

De plus, en anglais, le "flypaper" est référé comme un "fly-killing devices". Donc semblable au concept francophone.

Comment: Merci. Le _fly-killing device_ c'est un _dispositif servant à tuer les mouches_ ; dites-vous qu'en français on peut se passer du terme _dispositif_  et en faire un générique ?

Comment: Le mot _tue_ implique que c'est un dispositif.  Par exemple, si on avait un _fly-raising device_ (ou _fly-elevating device_), en français le verbe pour _elevate/raise_ est: _lever_. Alors le dispositif serait un: _lève-mouche_.